# ubuntu 21.04 keeps freezing. need help diagnosing

Tags: freeze, crash, 21.04

sometimes it lasts 5 minutes after boot, sometimes a few hours, but it always freezes. doesn't seem to be one process or app i've tested and had freezes under load and while idle.

I've ran memtest, 4/4 passes with 0 errors.
I've ran stress on the cpus for 3 hours at 100%, temps stable below 63C.
I've ran badblocks on each drive and found 0 errors

does ubuntu make crash logs or anything like that to help diagnose? any help is appreciated!

free -h https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QyhMfWjm8V/

swapon -s https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Z2KfnHc4wT/

cpus: 2x e5-2690 v1 mobo: x9dri-lnf4+

bios version https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ywf4X7Rd7h/

memory https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zXDyZ7XN3t/

swappiness https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tp7GzhBBTc/

/var/crash https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X3pYfmfzHS/ - i just installed kernel crash dump and i believe the files here are from a test crash the setup had me run to test if it was working

UPDATED
bmc firmware https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bShnFKFYCt/

bios version https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2Snsvb8cGk/

after running this fix I will test machine and get back to see if fix works.

syslog from boot to crash 1 - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VD9jSvRQBd/

syslog from boot to crash 2 - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KCScxkjydW/

gpu - MGA G200eW WPCM450 driver - mgag200

gnome-shell extensions https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YKXJzjVHTM/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7d672gCR3B/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y6SP4GKSpx/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Q62R3kX6sq/

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema added those command outputs let me know if you need more. thanks for helping btw

Comment: I don't think that 
`Swap:         7.8Gi          0B       7.8Gi` is good/normal, can someone correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @heynnema i sized my swap based on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/swapfaq

Comment: Thanks for the info. What kind of processor do you have? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Also show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: @Nate The column names are shifted left in this example, and as such, zero swap is shown as in `used`.

Comment: @heynnema updated with outputs!

Comment: @heynnema i updated the bios and firmware and will test the server. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

SuperMicro x9dri-ln4f+ *(note the corrected model #)*

You have BIOS 3.2, dated 03/04/2015. There's a newer BIOS available, version 3.4, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/bios_ipmi.php?vendor=1). Type "x9dri-ln4f+" into the search box. There's also a new BMC firmware "R 3.48" download.

[image]

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before performing the updates.

**Update #1:**

Added a Nvidia 710 video card, and so far, no freezing. This makes the MGA G200eW WPCM450 video card suspect.

**Update #2:**

It looks like the MGA G200eW WPCM450 video card is having a problem with Wayland.

We edited /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, uncommented this line: `#WaylandEnable=false`, saved the file, then rebooted.

So far no freezes!

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126496/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-21-04-keeps-freezing-need-help-diagnosi) which is hopefully more convenient for extended discussion.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1656957/slow-computer-because-of-bad-ssd